# problems starting WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: ubuntu, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2IS installed on a VM with ubuntu.
Last week I've reboot the server and upgrade the OS (now is Ubuntu 17.10).
It was ever gone well, but now when I write:
sh /opt/WSO2/wso2is-5.3.0/bin/wso2server.sh

this is the output:

JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /opt/WSO2/wso2is-5.3.0
Using Java memory options: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Is it possible that the guilty is of the upgrade of the OS?
Really I can't came out of this. Help please!

Comment: It might help if you can paste the stack trace itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolve it. It does not matter the ubuntu's upgrade.
I was accessing at the .sh file without "w" permission. So I've accessed with command 'sudo su -' and it works!

---

Note: only 'sudo su' makes lot of ERROR because it can't see $JAVA_HOME.